# Trigger does not update all the rows affected

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, openxml

I have 3 tables as Test 1, Test 2 and Test 3.

Test 1, is a sales table. where the sales details are recorded. and it will generate a sales id.

Test 2, is a table used to record all the products got sold in this specific sales id. i am  using openxml to insert these details. please find below the stored procedure used to update Test 1 and Test 2 tables.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateSales
(
@SalesID int out,
@SalesDate Date,
@XmlString text
) 
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY

INSERT INTO Test1 (SalesDate) VALUES (@SalesDate);
SET @SalesID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

DECLARE @XMLDocPointer int;
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @XMLDocPointer OUTPUT, @XmlString;

INSERT INTO Test2 (SalesID, ProductId, ProductName, qty)
    SELECT @SalesID, productId, productName, qty
    FROM OPENXML(@XmlDocPointer, '/Root/Products', 2)
    WITH (productId int,
        productName varchar(100),
        qty int);

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @XMLDocPointer 

COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH

END
GO
```

Table 3 is the product table. based on the sold product the quantity needs to be updated. i am using a trigger on the Test 2 table, after insert. please find below the trigger used.

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateQty ON Test2
AFTER INSERT
AS
DECLARE @productID int;
DECLARE @qty int;

SELECT @productID = ProductId FROM INSERTED;
SELECT @qty = qty FROM INSERTED;

DECLARE @currentQty int;
SELECT @currentQty = qty FROM Test3 WHERE productID = @productID;
UPDATE Test3 SET qty = @currentQty - @qty WHERE productID = @productID;
GO
```

when i tried to execute the stored procedure to insert the records to the Test 1 and Test 2 table since Test 3 table needs to be updated since i have a trigger. please find below the execute statement that i used, only the product id 1 is updated in the Test 3 table. Please help me to resolve this issue. tanx in advance.

Statement executed.

```
EXEC UpdateSales 
'1' , '08/08/2012' , 
'
<Root>
<Products>
<productId>1</productId>
<productName>Product 1</productName>
<qty>1</qty>
</Products>
<Products>
<productId>2</productId>
<productName>Product 2</productName>
<qty>2</qty>
</Products>
<Products>
<productId>3</productId>
<productName>Product 3</productName>
<qty>3</qty>
</Products>
</Root> 
'
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger is a single row trigger.  It needs to act on all records from the inserted table.

Untested, but your update trigger shouuld look something like this to update all affected rows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateQty ON Test2 
AFTER INSERT 
AS 

UPDATE Test3 
  SET qty = qty - i.qty
from test3 t
join inserted i on i.productid = t.productid

GO
```